# I want more images on my carousel but will only accept 16, why? How can I fix?

Tags: home, product-images

we have a carousel on our home page (the bottom carousel, the one with the logos. All is good except it will only take 16 images. I want at least 22 images, why? How can I fix?

http://www.amtservice.com

This code is placed on home page

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home-content" template="cms/content.phtml"}}
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="62" template="catalog/product/home-carousel.phtml"}}
```

A category was set up for these images. I create the image files in 'manage products'. Below is the code for the carousel. Thank you for your time.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<h3><?php echo $this->__('BRANDS SERVICED') ?><?php //echo $_productCollection->count(); ?></h3>
<div class="carousel">
    <ul class="slides">
         <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <li style="margin-right: 4px;"><a title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(112); ?>" width="112" height="112" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery(window).load(function() {
              jQuery('.carousel').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: false,
                reverse: false,
                slideshowSpeed: 3000,
                animationSpeed: 500, 
                controlNav: false,              
                itemWidth: 114,
                itemMargin: 0,
                minItems: 2,
                maxItems: 7
              });

            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Linda, please add some more info like the extension you're working with since this is a 3th party functionality and not core Magento.

Comment: Even if this question seems off-topic: Are there more than 16 products in your category with `category_id="62"`? And: There is a setting `maxItems: 7` in your JavaScript-Code. Try to set this to a higher value.

Answer (score 0):

You get only 16 because of the pagination.
I don't know if this is a Magento bug or a feature.
I think it's just a slip up or an uncovered case.
you are using a product list block and template. Before the collection is passed to the template it is processed by the paging block that ads a limit to the collection. I bet that if you change the paging options from the backend you will get more products in the slider also.
I'm not sure it will work but you can try this.
After the line:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

add this:

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->limit(22); //or any other limit.
```

In case you want all the products in your category instead of the line above use this. It will remove the sql limit completely (at least it should):

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
$_productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
```

And I assume you want the products to be listed in the order you set in the backend in your category. Just in case the sorting is saved in the session you might want to reset the order and put back the category order.
Below the line I mentioned add these 2 lines also:

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
$_productCollection->getSelect()->order('cat_index_position asc');
```